# how to use IN operator in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I have a table like the following

DealId  Categories
1         Clothes
2         Clothes,Shoes and accessories
3         Shoes and accessories
4         jewelery
5         Clothes,jewelery

Now suppose I get the categories like
`$data['categories']='clothes,Shoes and accessories';`

I use the following code:

```
$cat=$_REQUEST['categories'];
$query=mysql_query("select * from Deals where Categories IN ($cat)");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo json_encode($row);
}
```

and I got an error, I also used the `split()` function and other techniques I did not get good results with.
I need to select all rows that have 'Clothes' and 'Shoes and accessories'

Comment: you can use list instead of couple of `&nbsp;` in question

Comment: your code is vulnerable to sql injection ... consider using prepared statements

Comment: what error did you get? this is important to know and understand

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Answer (score 1):

your IN operator should be like this

```
IN('Clothes','Shoes','accessories','jewelery');
```

so your $cat variable should have value according to IN operater

Comment: the data i get dynamically like $data['categories']='Clothes,Shoes and Accessories'  yhis code will select all data. i have to selected only the data which is required

Comment: then use your selected data in format of  @Lokesh Jain answer

Answer (score 1):

```
The IN operator allows you to determine if a specified value matches any one of a list or a subquery
```

You can use it like

```
select * from Deals where Categories IN ('value1','value2' etc)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there's something wrong with the way you created your database, because it doesn't respect the first normal form.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms

Also, IN will compare a list of given values with the whole value of the field in the database (in your case e.g. 'Clothes, Shoes and accessories'), and mysql is not going to parse the string to find words inside it.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm

Answer (score 0):

i use like this Categories &2

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<?php
$cat=$_REQUEST['categories'];
$catArray=explode(",",$cat);
$sqlSearch='';
foreach($catArray as $onecat) {
    $sqlSearch= ($sqlSearch!=''?' OR':'WHERE ')."Categories LIKE '%".$onecat."%' "; 
}
$cat=str_replace(",","','",$cat);
$query=mysql_query("select * FROM Deals".$sqlSearch);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo json_encode($row);
}
?>
```